# AngularJS ng-click to display values on clicking

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

New to angular. So Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Do an $http get request to get a list of albums and show them in the UI as a list of URLs (Example of the response is ['album1', 'album2', 'album3']
2. When I click on album 1, I need to make a $http get request for album 1. When I click on album 2, I need to make a $http get request for album 2 and so on and display that response accordingly.

Here is what my code looks like. ( I know that the first get call will be made regardless but the subsequent calls will be on click events.)

```
// module
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.fileUploadForm', [
    'app.layout',
    'ui.router',
    'angularFileUpload'
]).config(FileUploadFormConfiguration);

FileUploadFormConfiguration.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
function FileUploadFormConfiguration($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('fileUploadForm', {
        url: '/fileUploadForm',
        parent: 'default',
        templateUrl: 'app/fileUploadForm/fileUploadForm.html',
        controller: 'FileUploadFormController as vm'
    });
}
})();


// Controller
(function (){

angular.module('app.fileUploadForm').controller('FileUploadFormController', FileUploadFormController);

FileUploadFormController.$inject = ['$http', '$log', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'APP_CONFIG'];
function FileUploadFormController ($http, $log, $scope, $rootScope, APP_CONFIG){

    var vm = this;
    vm.albums = init;
    vm.albums.tracks = getAlbumTracks;
    vm.newFunction = newFunction;

    return init();
    function init(){
     $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums').then(function(responseData){
            // Parse the json data here and display it in the UI
            $scope.vm.albums = responseData.data;
            $log.debug(angular.toJson(responseData, true));

//              console.log(vm.albums.tracks);
            return vm.albums;
        })
    }

    function getAlbumTracks(album, $scope){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/albums/'+album).success(function(trackResponse){
            //parse each album and get the track list
            $scope.vm.albums.tracks = vm.albums.tracks.concat(trackResponse);
            return vm.albums.tracks;
        })
    }

}

// HTML code:
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
hello!
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="album in vm.albums"><a href ng-click="vm.getAlbumTracks(album)">{{album}}</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="track in vm.albums.tracks"><a href ng-click="vm.displayForm(track)">{{track}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can see the list of albums but the second request to fetch the track info after clicking the album doesn't print anything. Any clue how to achieve that ? Thanks

Comment: i dont see displayForm function anywhere :)

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked I don't have it yet, since first the getAlbumTracks itself doesn't work so didn't want to throw it here :)

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked Let us just say that the displayForm for now says hello world but basically it will show a form when a track is clicked

Comment: Have you tried to use scope? `$scope.vm.albums = responseData.data;`

Comment: @developer033: just tried that. Didn't work :(

Comment: yeah, i got that with your first reply buddy :) can you like show your codes including the tag for app and controller. I might be of some help. And @developer033, when using alias, and assiging vm to this doesnt need scope to necesarrily get involved

Comment: @noobcoder You will probably get an accurate answer much faster if you create a sample project in JS Fiddle or Plunkr. Looking at the code you posted it's clear that important parts are missing, so it's hard to give an answer that is not a guess.

Comment: @Luis Perz: I hear you. But then I will not get the response from the get request sicne that is in my local a whole new project :(

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked updated my post

Comment: @noobcoder you are right. That part of the code would be mocked by replacing the `$http.get()` calls with `$q.when(["simulated result"])`.

Comment: do you see no error on console, whatsoever? have you tried alerting if your function is even called? and i agree with @LuisPerez, we can mock the call. If you can just created a plunker or fiddle of it

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked I just added the $window.alert in the getAlbumTracks function and when I click on any album, the window alert doesnt show up which means the function isn't getting called at all.

Comment: see now thats the problem, can you inspect and see what it throws error in console.

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked YEah I have been inspecting the element in the console but it doesn't throw any error on clicking. Neither does the function get called.

Comment: can you add $state.go('.',null,{reload:true}); just before your return vm.albums; in function init()

Comment: @AlexRumbaNicked I added it. But what should I expect. Actually it doesn't hit the return vm.albums line and is done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104684/discussion-between-alex-rumba-nicked-and-noobcoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by one line answer.

**changing:**

`vm.albums.tracks = getAlbumTracks;` to `vm.getAlbumTracks = getAlbumTracks;`

Comment: Thanks @Alex Rumba Nicked for offering to have a private chat and figuring out the goof up. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

While calling function of controller you should use controller alias before them. Like they are also belongs to `this` context of controller.

```
ng-click="vm.getAlbumTracks(album)"
ng-click="vm.displayForm(track)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized and I did that. Ill update my post. But it still didn't work